# Как можно присвоит значение если имя свойства совпадает с ключом объекта JObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp

У меня есть класс

```
public class ClientDossierModel
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Adress{ get; set; }
    public string Param{ get; set; }
}
```

И JObject объект
{"Name": "Addasd", "Address":"USA}

Как можно присвоит значение если имя свойства класса совпадает с ключом объекта JObject

Comment: Добрый день. Уточните, пожалуйста, желательно с примером, что именно вы имеете в виду. Пока в качестве ответа я вижу простую дессериализацию, но мне кажется вы имели в виду нечто другое

Comment: `clientDossierModel.Name = jObject["Name"].Value<string>();`